# Serialization UploadedFile

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle, vichuploaderbundle

If I have an upload User form (setting one field of an entity to UploadedFile), then the serialization of this entity will fail, since UploadedFile ($imageFile) is not serializable.

> [1/2] Exception: Serialization of
>   'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * Files
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 * @ORM\Table(name="files")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FilesRepository")
 */
class Files implements \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

        /**
     * NOTE: This is not a mapped field of entity metadata, just a simple property.
     * 
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="imageName", size="imageSize")
     * 
     * @var File
     */
    protected $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $imageName;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }





    /**
     * If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an instance
     * of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the  update. If this
     * bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is set to 'true' this setter
     * must be able to accept an instance of 'File' as the bundle will inject one here
     * during Doctrine hydration.
     *
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $image
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $image = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $image;

        if ($image) {
            // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
            // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return File|null
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageName
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setImageName($imageName)
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getImageName()
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

  /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->imageFile,

        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->imageFile,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like it would be obvious, but don't include the `imageFile` property when you serialize. What exactly are you trying to do? There is likely another way.

Comment: I'm trying to upload a file via a form.At first when i mixed oauthbundle with vichuploader i got the same exception, that's why i implemented the Serializble interface..any way this is the repo take a look https://github.com/bhss/campus